# How to run pre trained weights in darknet using python?

Tags: python-3.x, darknet

I want to run pre trained weights by using Darknet api in python.
Can any help me please how can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have compiled the darknet. Than you just put the pretrained weights into darknet folder and run:

```
./darknet detect cfg/yolov3.cfg pretrained.weights data/dog.jpg
```